# Compare a string from a csv file againt a lookup file in unix shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix

I am new to unix scripting. I have a requirement that I need to check a string from a csv file against a set of strings in another csv file. My file1 will have values like below,
**file1**

```
task desc
1    network error in there in line one.
2    data error is there in line three.
3    connection is missing from device.
4    new error is there
```

And `file2` will have the standard lookup data
**file2**

```
Network error
data error
connection is
```

The `file2` is static and my `file1` changes daily. My requirement is to check each line in the `file1` and check against the strings in `file2`. if there are any new error entry in the `file1`, then that entire row needs to be write into a new file called `file3`. this kind of daily standard error checking from a log file and report the new error. For example from my above example, the output `file3` needs to look like below.

**file3**

```
4    new error is there
```

Comment: `grep` is your friend. Read about its options `-v`, `-i` and `-f`.

Answer (score 0):

***tail*** + **grep** solution:

```
tail -n +2 file1 | grep -ivf file2 > file3
```

---

```
> cat file3
4    new error is there
```

---

- `tail -n +2 file1` - output the last part of `file1` starting from the 2nd line

*grep* options:

- `-f` - obtain patterns from file
- `-i` - caseinsensitive matching
- `-v` - invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines